# Force Mathematica to return numerical answer to (relatively) complicated differential function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, matrix, simplifying-expressions, special-functions

I am trying to take the Laplacian of the LogDet of a 2x2 matrix that I call `V\[ConjugateTranspose].V`, and actually get a number out at the end. Why does Mathematica refuse to simplify the final expression and give a number? The full programme is as follows:

```
In[1]:= (* Define parameters *)

d = 4; (* !! *)
N1 = 1; N2 = 1; (*Number of unit cells*)

tau = Exp[I \[Pi]/2]; (* \[Gamma]2=tau*\[Gamma]1*)
gam1 := \[Pi] Sqrt[
  d]; gam2 := \[Pi] Sqrt[d] tau;
M = 2;


thetap[x_, y_, p_] := (
  E^(-((I (Sqrt[d] \[Pi] tau - 2 (x + I*y))^2)/(4 \[Pi] tau)))
    EllipticTheta[
    3, -(((d + 2 p) \[Pi])/(2 d)) + (x + I*y)/(Sqrt[d] tau), 
    E^(-((I \[Pi])/(d tau)))])/Sqrt[-I d tau]; 
thetabasis[x_, y_] = 
  Table[{thetap[x, y, p]}, {p, 0, d - 1}]; (* (dx1)column *)

Cmatrix1 := IdentityMatrix[d]; 
psi1[x_, y_] =  Cmatrix1.thetabasis[x, y];
MatrixForm[%]


In[79]:= 
w = 1*tau*gam1/d; (* Displacement vector*)

V[x_, y_] := 
 With[{ x0 = Re[w], y0 = Im[w]}, 
  Join[psi1[x, y], psi1[x - x0, y - y0], 2]]
Dimensions[V[1, 1]]

(*Take LogDet of V\[ConjugateTranspose].V *)

f[x_, y_] := Log[Det[V[x, y]\[ConjugateTranspose].V[x, y]]];
Q[x_, y_] := Laplacian[f[a, b], {a, b}] /. {a -> x, b -> y} ;
Q[1, 1]

Out[80]= {4, 2}
In[116]:= Chop[N[Q[1, 1]]] // FullSimplify


Out[116]= (0. - 8.67362*10^-19 I) Derivative[1][
   Conjugate][-0.0464237 + 0.310723 I]^2 + 
 Derivative[1][Conjugate][
   0.121276 - 
    0.619273 I] ((1.11022*10^-16 + 
      5.55112*10^-17 I) - (8.88178*10^-16 + 
       4.44089*10^-16 I) Derivative[1][Conjugate][1.]) - 
 1.77636*10^-15 Derivative[1][Conjugate][
   1.]^2 + (5.55112*10^-17 - 5.55112*10^-17 I) Derivative[1][
   Conjugate][1.60785 + 1.18905 I]^2 + 
 Derivative[1][Conjugate][
   1.60785 + 1.18905 I] ((8.88178*10^-16 + 2.22045*10^-16 I) - 
    1.11022*10^-16 Derivative[1][Conjugate][2.3168 - 0.881071 I]) + 
 Derivative[1][
   Conjugate][-0.0464237 + 
    0.310723 I] ((-2.60209*10^-18 + 3.46945*10^-18 I) Derivative[1][
      Conjugate][
      0.121276 - 0.619273 I] + (5.55112*10^-16 + 
       4.64906*10^-16 I) Derivative[1][Conjugate][1.] - 
    1.38778*10^-17 Derivative[1][Conjugate][2.3168 - 0.881071 I]) + 
 Derivative[1][Conjugate][
   1.] ((-1.42109*10^-14 - 
      8.88178*10^-15 I) + (0. + 6.66134*10^-16 I) Derivative[1][
      Conjugate][
      0.121276 - 0.619273 I] + (1.77636*10^-15 + 
       1.22125*10^-15 I) Derivative[1][Conjugate][
      1.60785 + 1.18905 I] - (0. + 1.79023*10^-15 I) Derivative[1][
      Conjugate][2.3168 - 0.881071 I]) + 
 1.77636*10^-15 Derivative[1][Conjugate][
   2.3168 - 0.881071 I] - (5. + 2.45352 I) (
   Conjugate^\[Prime]\[Prime])[1.]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
f[x_, y_] = 
  Block[{x, y}, Assuming[x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals,
    Log[Det[V[x, y]\[ConjugateTranspose].V[x, y]]] /. 
      e : Conjugate[EllipticTheta[a_, z_, q_]] :> 
       EllipticTheta[a, Conjugate[z], q] // Simplify
    ]
   ];

Chop[N[Q[1, 1]]]
(*  2.10739  *)
```

Comment: It seems a shortcoming of Mathematica that `FullSimplify[Conjugate[EllipticTheta[a, u, q]]]` is unable to return `EllipticTheta[a, Conjugate[u], Conjugate[q]]` without help.  `FullSimplify[Conjugate[Sin[x]]]`, on the other hand, returns `Sin[Conjugate[x]]`.

Comment: @Michael E2, thank you for you response, but could you please explain why it is not working in the following case. I expand the definition of V[x,y] to V[x,y,x0,y0], so now f[] and V[] should change correspondingly. Why does the following not work? I do f[x_, y_, x0_, y0_] = Block[{x, y, x0, y0}, Assuming[ x \[Element] Reals && y \[Element] Reals && x0 \[Element] Reals && y0 \[Element] Reals, Log[Det[V[x, y, x0, y0]\[ConjugateTranspose].V[x, y, x0, y0]]] /. e : Conjugate[EllipticTheta[a_, z_, q_]] :> EllipticTheta[a, Conjugate[z], q] // Simplify]];

Comment: @ap21 There's an expression `Conjugate[x + I (y - y0)]` that is not simplified by `Simplify`.  `FullSimplify` will do it, but apply `/. z_Conjugate :> FullSimplify[z]` after the regular `Simplify` (inside `Assuming`).  Using `FullSimplify` on the full expression with the theta functions takes a long time.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thanks again. I did what you said: ` \\Simplify /. Conjugate[z_] :> FullSimplify[z]`, but it does not work. I presume that `z_Conjugate` and `Conjugate[z]` are equivalent. Do you have any other suggestions, or should I just be content with the `FullSimplify`?

Comment: @ap21 Because of precedence rules, you have to put parentheses around `(expr // Simplify) /. rule` or like this `Simplify[expr] /. rule`. Note that `z_Conjugate` is equivalent to `z : Conjugate[_]` and not to `Conjugate[z_]`. In the first case `z` matches the whole `Conjugate` expression, and in the second `z` matches only the argument of `Conjugate` effectively undoing the conjugation, which is not what you want.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you very much! I learnt and re-learnt many things with your help.